# Frankenstein Words

Tags: code-golf, string

For this challenge you need to make a given word by concatenating "pieces" (a.k.a contiguous substrings) from other words. Given a word and a list of words as input, output the fewest number of pieces needed to create the first word.

## Rules

- Words consist of characters in the ASCII range 33 to 126.
- The word list may have repeats.
- Construction of words is case sensitive (you can not use the piece "Head" as part of the word "forehead".)
- Once you have used a piece in a construction, you can not use any part of that piece again (e.g if I use "lo" from "lone" as part of constructing "lolo", I cannot use "lo" from that "lone" again. However, if I had two "lone" in my word list, I could use one "lo" from each.)
- Once you use a piece, you can still make pieces out of unused substrings in the word. (E.g. If I used "tt" in "butter", I still have "bu" and "er" left over to use. However, I can't combine them into one "buer" piece.)
- If it is impossible to construct the input word using the word list given, output nothing, or something other than a positive integer.

## Examples

(you only need to output the number)

- `"snack" ["food","Shoe","snack"]` => 1 (`snack`)
- `"Snack" ["food","Shoe","snack"]` => 2 (`S` + `nack`)
- `"frog" ["cat","dog","log"]` => 0
- `"~~Frank~~" ["Frog~","~~Love","Hank~"]` => 4 (`~~` + `Fr` + `ank~` + `~`)
- `"loop-de-loop" ["loop", "frien-d","-elk","pool"]` => 7 (`loop` + `-d` + `e` + `-` + `l` + `oo` + `p`)
- `"banana" ["can","can","boa"]` => 4 (`b`+`an`+`an`+`a`)
- `"banana" ["can","boa"]` => 0
- `"13frnd" ["fr13nd"]` => 3 (`13` + `fr` + `nd`)

Let me know if you think of more useful test cases.

Comment: *pieces* are usually called *contiguous substrings*.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>209</s> 206 bytes

```
f=(a,b,F)=>a?[...a].map((_,i)=>[...Array(i+1)].map((_,j)=>F||b.forEach((q,k)=>!F&&~(I=q.indexOf(a[S='substring'](j,r=a.length-i+j)))&&(F=b[k]=q[S](0,I)+' '+q[S](I+r+j),a=a[S](0,j)+a[S](r)))))&&F&&1+f(a,b):0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jZJfa4MwFMXf@ymcD22CUSp7m6RjjMkKgz34KGFcNbb@WdJGVzbW@dW7G9vJXgZDSE7O@cXcq6nhAF1uql3vK13I0wGM08uuv4dOdg530pnjpG6nIG9chqrUunCZm2y1xOnsC8FGKvkXVRq9GaEcegwLu3JbHH@AYYgNqGYYRipGHBW6T/pg3/Zoswlutd75hfTtPPIXgcdUUvm2Cl@2WJW707qdtmWg8LmUoTA9j5mGv5HfYXhdGlWcezXhNUohZiI6lZwAy1hM@Qpu0yAIQASvsCPkhVXoWefOGPgglRfSKaoxio/HLCi1eYB8S8ieNehdxfP5QNZ8H1SqkO/PJYE04YvuLet6U6nNQpCaGQ5BK9Wm3/qVV1NK53MS8yxtBN@niSBLtqbewll442rtGYQYcDhnNfVGZSgdt@KJoVfaJujN8hRNV2EqzToOXzmf@B1yrTrdygD/HikJ9mZDSqPZF41O3w)

Returns `NaN` if the combination is not found.